# complex analysis - Cauchy's inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let f be an entire function. Suppose $\exists$ $M>0$ such that
>   $\mid$$f(z)$$\mid$ $\leq$ $M$$\mid$$z$$\mid$ $\forall$
>   $z$$\in$$\Bbb{C}$. Show that $\exists$$\lambda$$\in$$\Bbb{C}$ such
>   that f(z)=$\lambda$$z$ $\forall$ $z$$\in$$\Bbb{C}$.

This problem is related to Liouville's theorem (which is a corollary of the cauchy inequalities) and someone told me use function g(z)=f(z)/z.
But since g(z) is not 'entire' function, I don't really know how to use this function to solve this problem. How can I solve this matter?

Comment: Hint: Liouville's theorem (which is a corollary of the cauchy inequalities)

Comment: Another hint: consider $g(z) = f(z)/z$.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! But I have something trouble. Since g(z)=f(z)/z is not a bdd 'entire' function, I think I can't use Liouville's theorem. How can I solve this matter?

Comment: Why is it not entire? Note that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't it a sigular point z=0 on g(z)=f(z)/z?

Comment: Depends on $f$. Here $f$ is entire and $f(0)=0$ hence the power series at $0$ is $f(z)=a_1z+a_2z^2+\dots$, and [its radius is infinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843858/radius-of-convergence-of-entire-function). Conclusion about $g$?

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your advice. Have a nice day : )